# Getting jQuery $.post to send data to a PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, post, click

I'm trying to post some data to a PHP file using jQuery. If I send the data via a form everything works just fine, but I want it to send in the background via jQuery. The click function works (except `$.post`), because I have tested it with an `alert()` and when I comment out the `$.post` line everything else works. If I don't comment out the `$.post` line the last two lines don't work.

Here is my javascript stored in `admin.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".admin-refresh").click(function () {
        var movieID = $(this).prev().text();
        $.post("actions.php", {refreshMovie: yes, movieID: movieID});
        $(this).removeClass('btn-warning');
        $(this).addClass('btn-success');
    });

});
```

Here is some of the code from `actions.php`. This file is working if I post the data via form.

```
//Refresh Movie Details
if ($_POST['refreshMovie']) {

  $movieID = $_POST['movieID'];
```

Here is the code from `active-movies.php`, which contains the button that activates the javascript.

```
<button class="btn admin-refresh"><i class="icon-refresh"></i> Refresh</button>
```

The files are stored as such `ROOT/admin/active-movies.php`, `ROOT/admin/actions.php`, and `ROOT/includes/js/admin.js`.

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: Tried debugging with the console?

Comment: Check errors in your browser's JS console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least one of your problems is here.

```
{refreshMovie: yes, movieID: movieID}
```

should be

```
{refreshMovie: "yes", movieID: movieID}
```

Comment: That did the trick! I'll accept your answer when I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a third argument to the `$.post()` (a callback) like:

```
$.post("actions.php", {refreshMovie: yes, movieID: movieID}, function(response){
    // actions.php should return some data to check if the 
    // action was successful
    // that data will be available as a variable ("response")
   if ( response == 'success' ) {
       // do something
   } else {
       // do something else
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Everything is working, but I agree with you that having a callback to confirm success or failure would be a good idea. How would I send a callback/response from a PHP file (actions.php) to admin.js? If it is too complicated to explain here, I can just look it up, but I thought your explanation above was good and thought you might have a quick example of how I could implement a callback. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Just enclose the parameters names into quotes, because the JS will make the mistake to think that `movieID:movieID` is like `Kung Fu Panda:Kung Fu Panda`.

```
{'refreshMovie': 'yes', 'movieID': movieID}
```

Comment: Not true. Object property names are not evaluated. Eg. `a = 'foo'; { a : 'bar' }` produces an object `{ a : bar }`, not `{ foo : bar }`. You *can*, however, do that using array notation - e.g. `"a = 'foo'; b = {}; b[a] = 'bar';`

Comment: Yes and thats why if ther is movieId=5 the code will be interpreted as 5:5, you said it in your comment, but in different way :)

Comment: No, that's exactly NOT what I'm saying. I'm saying the opposite.

Comment: Ok I agree with you. I didn't say that.